# VS2017 Project fallback framework error when building solution

Tags: c#, msbuild, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I have a .NET Core solution which is resulting in below error when I build - it was originally pointing to .NET Core 2.0 now pointing to .NET Core 2.1 and this error is appearing since.

I have tried to search the internet but couldn't find anyone who has had the same problem.

Error attached below:

[image]

Project file below

```
 <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
    <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
      <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
      <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
      <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
      <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <AssetTargetFallback>%3bnet461%3bportable-net45+win8</AssetTargetFallback>
   </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
      <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
     <Compile Remove="Controllers\TestController.cs" />
     <Compile Remove="Controllers\ValuesController.cs" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="EvoHtmlToPdf_NetCore_Client" Version="7.5.0" 
    />
    <PackageReference Include="Kendo.Mvc" Version="2016.2.616" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication" 
     Version="2.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="2.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization" Version="2.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy" Version="2.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" Version="5.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Mime" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IO.FileSystem" Version="4.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\TEST\DataLayer.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="AppSettings.cs.d.ts">
      <DependentUpon>AppSettings.cs</DependentUpon>
    </None>
```

Comment: Fallback frameworks are relatively rarely needed these days, particularly the PCL-based one - are you sure you need it at all? Could you post your complete project file?

Comment: Even if you needed it, that `;` at the beginning shouldn't be there

Comment: @JonSkeet looks like it's this line <AssetTargetFallback>%3bnet461%3bportable-net45+win8</AssetTargetFallback>

Comment: As Jon mentioned, if you don't need that line, remove it. And as I said, if you need that line, remove that  `%3b` from the start of the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing this line fixed it - thanks to Jon and Camilo

```
<AssetTargetFallback>%3bnet461%3bportable-net45+win8</AssetTargetFallback>
```